# Real time charting with Plotly and Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I need to add a real-time chart to my Flask-SocketIO app, for that i found Plotly.

Would it be possible with Plotly to generate a chart which shows both real-time data and past data? When the user opens the page he should be able to see both the data from before the webpage was opened and the new data. How would it be possible to accomplish that with Plotly? Is there an example for it?

Comment: This is pretty broad/vague. What is the data about? Is it just stored in a database? If so it is certainly possible.

Comment: I would like to store it in arrays, the data is just a single number

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of apps it's highly recommended to feed your real time data to a database and connect your visualization with said database, however I think it is possible to achieve what you want in jupyter notebook with plotly 3 `FigureWidget`'s `batch_update`. I can't quite get the idea of what you want without some code though.